# Show the latest post from child category?

Tags: categories, query-posts

How do i show the latest post from a child category?

I have the category Photos, but I want to only show the latest post from the Child category "Paparazzi"

what do i add to the code below to do this

```
<?php 
query_posts('category_name=photos&showposts=1'); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your query to search for the category you want.

```
$qry = new WP_Query('category_name=paparazzi&showposts=1');
while($qry->have_posts()) : $qry->the_post();
```

That should most likely be all you need to do.

And please don't use `query_posts`. It alters the main query and can break things.

Comment: That didn't work, because paprazzi is a child category

Comment: That doesn't matter. The query doesn't care about the parent/child status, and I have tested that. You do need to [use the _slug_ and not the name though](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).